# $\int_V \left( g\nabla^2f-f \nabla^2g \right) dV=\int_S \left( g\nabla f-f \nabla g \right) \cdot u_n \, dS$ not depend on time

Tags: integration, laplacian, greens-theorem, gradient-flows

I' m wondering why the following relationship, known as Green's identity, doesn't depends on time.

Let

$f(x,y,z,t)$ and $g=\frac{e^{ikr}}{r}$

so

$$\int_V \left( g\nabla^2f-f \nabla^2g \right) dV=\int_S  \left( g\nabla f-f \nabla g \right) \cdot u_n \, dS$$

Comment: Assuming $dV$ is the volume form in $xyz$-space, both the quantity on the right-hand side of your equality and the quantity on the left-hand side of your equality depend on $t$. Thus, your equality should be interpreted as equality of functions of $t$ (i.e. for each fixed $t$ the left-hand side equals the right-hand side).

Answer (score 1):

The identity is easily shown using the divergence theorem:
$$
\int_V \left( g \, \nabla^2 f - f \, \nabla^2 g \right) dV
= \int_V \nabla \cdot \left( g \, \nabla f - f \, \nabla g \right) dV
= \oint_S  \left( g \, \nabla f - f \, \nabla g \right) \cdot u_n \, dS
$$
Both $f$ and $g$ may depend on $t$, but this dependency does not enter the identity. There will be no derivatives w.r.t. $t$. That is related to the integral $\int \cdot \, dV$ being only over space, not over time.